# iPhone - UIView's backgroundColor - using a png with transparency?

Tags: iphone, uiview, png, transparency, background-color

I'm setting the background color of my UIView (which is within a UIViewController) as follows:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myTransparentBG.png"]];
```

I've even tried messing with `[myView setOpaque:NO];` but the image doesn't appear transparent. It has a black background to it. Am I abel to fix this programmatically? Otherwise, how are we supposed to set a transparent background to our view?

This seems like a question that should have been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When using a transparent pattern, after setting the backgroundColor property, you need to set `opaque` property to `NO` on both view and its layer. Here's a sample:

```
UIView* paperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,700)];
paperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.png"]];

[paperView.layer setOpaque:NO];
paperView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: Aha, this is the correct answer. I wasn't setting the layer's opaque property. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly you must set the opaque property *after* you set the background image. Must be part of the rendering engine.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I had the same problem.  Also: the last two lines of this code snippet do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was looking for this since long. Thanks again.

Comment: One of the best answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever actually done this, but here's what I'd try.

Set the UIView's `.backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`. Then put a UIImageView containing your PNG as the "lowest" item on the UIView's stack of subviews. Make sure the UIImageView's background color is also clear.

Comment: Actually, there wasn't much of a reason to keep the UIView, I ended up just using a UIImageView and then adding all of the other elements as subviews of that and it works really well.

Comment: @RyanJM Oh yeah. I sometimes forget that as a UIView subview, UIImageView can happily hold subviews...

Answer (score -1):

Use this: myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

This will set it to a transparent background.

Comment: On it? I want the image to be the background. I have other UI elements inside the view.

Comment: If u set the UIView color to clearColor, then it will be transparent. Depending where the images and other views are ordered, you can play around with them.