# How to preserve image transparency when using colorWithPatternImage:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have an image prepared with transparency, like this:

[image]

With two UIviews, I configure the background colors as so:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
self.dashedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_square.png"]];
```

I expect the red square to be repeated over the UIView with transparency preserved, but it's been filled by a solid color like this:

[image]

I don't understand why. Is there a simple way to draw a tiled image with transparency? Or do I need to look at drawing Core Graphics patterns?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pattern images should be keeping the transparency just fine.

Try `[self.dashedView setOpaque:NO]`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I previously tried this through Interface Builder, and that doesn't seem to work. Setting it programatically does, however.

Comment: There are some issues with those options through IB, I've run into that a number of times. I think its an initialization order issue potentially.

Comment: For posterity, I found it necessary to set the layer as non-opaque as well, e.g.: [self.dashedView.layer setOpaque:NO]. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059487/iphone-uiviews-backgroundcolor-using-a-png-with-transparency

Comment: I have no idea why, but I've found it necessary to set opaque to YES, set the background color to the patterned image, then set opaque back to NO. I cannot explain this in the slightest, however.

Comment: Same issue as Yar here, except opaque can be selected in IB. Apparently the pattern image needs to be set while the view is opaque, and then turned transparent afterward.

Answer (score 5):

all you have to do is set opaque to NO after setting the colorWithPatternImage.

```
self.dashedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_square.png"]];
self.dashedView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: Indeed, the important thing for 4.3 is to set the Opaque after setting the background colour (or the image in the case of a UIImageView).

Answer (score 3):

Yar, thanks for the feedback.

I found this only happens on iOS 4.3.x but not on iOS 5.0.x. So on 4.3.x I had to do what Yar id and set opaque to NO, then set background image, then set to YES.

```
UIButton* cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cancelButton.opaque = YES; // fix for strange issue in 4.x, need to set YES, set bg color image, then set back to NO
cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: cancelImage];
cancelButton.opaque = NO;
```