# UIView Background Image Transparency Problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, transparency

I added a subview with an PNG image that should display with transparency, but I am getting all black where the transparency should be.

The code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BannerBackground.png"]];
    logoImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 56)];
    logoImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:logoImage];

}
```

This is code for a iPad, iOS version 4.3. I have the same problem with both the simulator and the iPad.

Since this is the last view added, I expect it to have a z index higher than all of the other views, so the other views should show through the transparent areas. This is not working.

Comment: I've got this same issue for a number of transparency images.  It seems like an undocumented iOS 4.3 bug. :-/  I can replicate this on a simulator, but not on a device as I don't have any devices running 4.3 to test with.

Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[I noticed this behaves differently on iOS 4.3.x than 5.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209383/how-to-preserve-image-transparency-when-using-colorwithpatternimage/8896838#8896838).  In 4.3.x I had to set opaque to YES, then set the background image, then set it back to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Set your view's property opaque to no. like this [view setOpaque:NO];

Comment: I tried the suggestions above and then tried a PNG from a web page where I knew the image transparency was working. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Failing setOpaque:NO... check to see if your image is correctly exported and not corrupted etc.. that happened to me once

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work. Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIImageView with transparent backgroundColor and your logo as its image, and add that:

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
logoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:logoView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>



logoImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 56)];
logoImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
[logoImage.layer setOpaque:NO];
logoImage.opaque = NO;


[self.view addSubview:logoImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but: any chance that your transparency is, for instance, black and not actually transparent?  Not that I just did that or anything.

(When drawing the toolbar icon, iOS fills in any pixels, including black ones, with white.  Make sure there's actually nothing where you expect your transparent area to be.)