# Transparent .png not transparent in iOS 4, looks fine in iOS 5

Tags: ios, png

Take a look:

[image]

[image]

This is the code I use to make the gradient:

```
gradView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 440, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
gradView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sepGrad.png"]];
gradView.alpha = 0.2;
[self.view addSubview:gradView];
```

And the .png files:

[image]
[image]

Why would iOS4 be unable to display the transparent .png properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in iOS 4.3, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896838/429331

In your case:

```
gradView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 440, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)]; 
gradView.opaque = YES;
gradView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sepGrad.png"]];
gradView.opaque = NO;
gradView.alpha = 0.2;
[self.view addSubview:gradView];
```

You could also try to omit `gradView.opaque = YES;`, I'm not sure if it's really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the bug to my attention. `gradView.opaque = NO` fixed it for me.